# How to Retrieve and Send Html String to server in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, xcode, rest, cocoa-touch

I’ve been facing problem to retrieve HTML response from server and show it in UITextView ( i am using REST Api).

I wanted to send that again to remote server with modification  of HTML string.

I’ve little bit idea about NSAttributedString and NSMutableString
Here is an Example String that I want to get it from server and display to UITextView and send it back to server after some operation.

```
<b>Soaking time</b>:&nbsp; 3 hours <br>
<b>Preparation time:</b> 15 mins <br>
<b>Fermenting time:</b>&nbsp; 8 hours <br>
<span><b>Cooking time:</b> 45 mins<br><br></span>
1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Soak the urad dal (split black lentils)&nbsp;and fenugreek seeds (methi)&nbsp;together in water for 3 hours and drain. <br>
2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Soak the parboiled rice in water for 3 hours and drain. <br>
3.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Blend urad dal and fenugreek seeds together in a mixer till smooth and frothy (add water little by little as required) remove and keep aside. <br>
4.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Blend the rice in a mixer till smooth. Remove and keep aside. <br>
5.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Combine the urad dal paste and rice paste together in a bowl and keep aside to ferment overnight. <br>
6.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Once the batter is fermented, add salt to the batter and mix well. <br>
7.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Put spoonfuls of the batter into greased idli moulds and steam for 10 to 12 minutes. <br>
8.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Serve at room temperature. <br>
```

I stuck here with current scenario as above.. Any help will be really appreciated.Thanks